# dropdown selected value in typescript angularjs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown and apply button in my html, and in my ts file, I have apply() function and array declared. I am able to display the dropdown with values in my front end, but when I click on the apply button, I dont get the selected value from the dropdown. I use a lert box for now to display the selected value.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputdefault" class="control-label col-sm-2">Portal:</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <select class="form-control" id="inputdefault" name = "portal">
                        <option *ngFor="let c of portalValues">{{c.group}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="apply(portal)">Apply</button>                    
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" (click)="cancel()">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In ts,

```
 portalValues: Array<Object> = [{id:1, group:'Enterprise'},{id:2, group:'Business'}];

apply(portal:any) {
     alert(portal);
  }
```

and alert value is displayed as undefined. How to get the selected value from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `portal` argument you are passing isn't defined. There are multiple ways to do this. One would simply be to declare a [Template Reference Variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars).

For example:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="inputdefault" name = "portal" #portalSelect>
  <option [value]="c.group" *ngFor="let c of portalValues">{{c.group}}</option>
</select>
```

Two things happened here:

1. I added `#portalSelect` to the select element so I can reference it.
2. I added the `[value]` attribute binding to the option elements and bound it to the `group` property (you can bind this to what you see fit, but if you want to bind to the object itself you need to use `[ngValue]` instead)

Then when you pass the selected portal to your component function you can use `apply(portalSelect.value)`.

If you need forms support or you want to bind the selection to your component you will want to use [`[(ngModel)]`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html). In this case you would want to provide a property on your component for the selected value, and bind to it as such:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPortal">
...
```

and in your component

```ts
selectedPortal: any;

apply() {
  // do something with this.selectedPortal
}
```

Comment: Can you also take a look at this , I have a similar query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046557/table-do-not-change-when-response-changes-angular2-webpack?noredirect=1#comment71414789_42046557

Comment: No problem and will do

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `ngModel` in your `select` input. Something like this should do it. This way the variable `portal` binds to the value chosen by the dropdown. `name` attribute does not do this.

```
<select class="form-control" id="inputdefault" [(ngModel)]="portal" name = "portal">
     <option *ngFor="let c of portalValues">{{c.group}} </option>
</select>
```

You may also need to include this in your `select` tag:
`#name="ngModel"`